# Android stretch layout widths: absolute width + percentage

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 buttons, first button should have 100dp width, second button would be (parent - 100dp) width.

Is that possible to achieve?

I tried the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout as a parent? It can easily be achieved using RelativeLayout

Comment: ButtonBarLayout extends LinearLayout right? Setting the weightSum of the ButtonBarLayout to 1 and the layout_width of the second button to 0dp should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **RelativeLayout** as parent:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```